# On entire functions of slow growth

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone shed light on the following problem? It is Problem 2 in Page 3 of *Lectures on Entire Functions* by Levin.

> Let $\psi: [0, \infty]\to [0, \infty] $ be an arbitrary function
>   which is monotonically increasing without bound. Construct an entire
>   function $f(z)$ which is not a polynomial and satisfies the inequality
>   $$\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|\leqslant 1+ r^{\psi(r)}$$

This is not homework by the way. Just something that I am curious to know.

The hint given in the book is: Look for a function in the form of a power series with positive coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible construction: By assumption, for every $n \ge 1$ there exists $r_n \ge 1$ such that $\psi(r) \ge n$ for all $r \ge r_n$. This implies that $r^n \le r^{\psi(r)}$ for all $r \ge r_n$. Then there exists $a_n > 0$ such that $a_n r^n \le 2^{-n} r^{\psi(r)}$ for all $r \ge 1$. Now define $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$. For $|z|=r$ we have
\begin{align*}
|f(z)| &= \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n r^n \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} r^{\psi(r)} = r^{\psi(r)}
\end{align*}
for all $z$ with $|z|=r \ge 1$. By the maximum principle, for $|z| \le 1$ we get $|f(z)| \le 1^{\psi(1)} = 1$, so $|f(z)| \le 1+r^{\psi(r)}$ for all $z$ with $|z|=r$. By construction $f$ has infinitely many non-zero power series coefficients, so it is not a polynomial.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.